Can I Generate and Send Excel File via Email in Pentaho?
Output: The transformation will send the product master data in the form of an Excel file with the name data_excel_yyyy-MM-dd.xls, where yyyy represents the year, MM represents the month, and dd represents the day.
Maybe it could be like this
